# How to click on a download button with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I try to scrap some informations on a website.
There is my code

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyvirtualdisplay

class Informations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_site_by_siren = ["418 096 392", "334 992 798"]
        self.website = "https://www.pappers.fr/"

def main():
    informations = Informations()
    print(informations.list_site_by_siren)
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.set_window_size(1920,1500)

    driver.get(informations.website)

    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Entreprise, N° SIREN, Dirigeant, Mot-clé...']").send_keys(informations.list_site_by_siren[0])


    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Rechercher"]').click()

    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Voir les comptes")]').click()
    #driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button mt2").click() same but doesnt work too
```

my driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button mt2").click() doesn't work.

[image]

i would like to click  on "Voir les comptes" and start the force the download of the file but i don't know how to do that.

this is the html code

```
<a href="micromania-418096392/comptes/MICROMANIA - Comptes sociaux 2022 19-07-2022.pdf" title="Voir les comptes 2022-01-31 de MICROMANIA" target="_blank" class="button mt2">VOIR LES COMPTES <span class="fas fa-download" style="margin-left: 4px;"></span></a>
```

So at first i have to locate micromania-418096392/comptes/MICROMANIA - Comptes sociaux 2022 19-07-2022.pdf and the second part is to download it but i dont find how i can do that and actually it doesn't detect the button.

Thanks for yours answers!

Answer (score 1):

this line can get you nothing: `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button mt2").click()`  because you actually look not for this `"button mt2"` but for this `" 'button mt2' "`, it tries to find class with name 'button mt2' (=it looks for one name, not for two ones). of course there is no class with such name and it finds nothing.
solutions:

1. you can try to find all 'buttons' (or all 'mt2') by `find_elements()` (..ntS) and iterate to what you need ->`driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "button")`
2. you can use xpath() or something else (but not `By.Class` parameter)

Comment: Thanks for yours answer: I have even tried to do this :     driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Voir les comptes")]').click()
 but it still doesn't work. (but i didnt know for  "'button mt2", thanks)

Comment: this `var_a = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "button")` puts into `var_a` a list with all 'buttons' on the page as elements, I guess there are not many, you can iterate this list find the button you need and use it. the same thing you can do with this line `var_a = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "mt2")`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath to get the button -

```
//a[contains(@title,'Voir les comptes')]/span[@class='fas fa-download']
```

Comment: is it python code?

Comment: No. This is a xpath.

Answer (score 0):

`driver.get(driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "button mt2").get_attribute("href"))`

Comment: it does nothing i don't know why

Comment: this gives me ```elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button mt2"}````